# CUI command error on Windows 10 folder sharing function

Tags: windows, shell, directory

I really need your help...

I have 2 machines, and both systems are windows 10. 
I'm trying to connect them with Ethernet cable and working them as mail and calculation server.

I connect them and make setting for sharing folders, and GUI become works well. But on command prompt, couldn't work.

from calculation server, it behave like below.

```
> net view
MachineA
> net view \\MachineA
FolderA
FolderB
> net view \\MachineA\FolderA
ERROR : System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found
```

And, from mail server, it behave like below.

```
> net view
ERROR : System error 64 has occurred.
```

On both system, GUI works well, which means file can create/edit/delete each other. Could I have your advice?
Thank you.

Comment: [net view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh875576(v=ws.11)): Displays a list of domains, computers, or resources that are being shared by the specified computer.  [net share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh750728(v=ws.11)) Allows you to map the network share to a drive or folder so you can access its files.

Comment: Do note this question could be considered as not related to coding, perhaps superuser?

Comment: > bradbury9 Thank you very match for your comment. This error not relate with superuser since it's same symptom if I tried with admin account. And, I also confirmed file sharing was setting properly with "net share" command.